# Override method parameters in abstract class

Tags: java, abstract

I am creating an abstract class, that will be implemented by some projects.

These projects, will implement that class, and their methods also.

```
protected String setExitStatus(SortDto sortDto) {
    if (sortDto.getTotalNumberOfPages() > 0) {
        return "DATOS";
    } else {
        return "SINDATOS";
    }
}
```

As you can see, this method by defect has a SortDto as a parameter.

What if, the developer that wants to use that method, but don't want to (or does not have) to supply a SortDto, and instead wants to supply another dto? or another pair of dtos?

Is there any way I can define this method, that by default, wants a SortDto, but it can be override with another argument?

Comment: Think of it from the *caller's* perspective. If the abstract class is vague about what's required, how is the caller going to know what to provide? If a concrete implementation expects two parameters, but the caller only provides one, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: You shouldn't name the argument the exact same (including casing) as the Type. That will cause inevitable errors.

Comment: Maybe I am not explaning well enough. By default, that logic will be used and that argument will be used. But if the developer wants to do that method in another way. How can I let the developer define their own arguments?

Comment: Developers "defining their own arguments" are effectively writing new methods and not implementing the abstract method.

Comment: Providing a different method with the same name, but different parameters is called "overloading", not "overriding".

Comment: Do all of your DTOs have a `getTotalNumberOfPages()` method?

Comment: No, only sortDto. But maybe the developer does not need or want to use that dto, and instead want another argument.

Comment: If the developer doesn't want or need to use that DTO, then why are they inheriting from this Abstract Class? I would reconsider your class hierarchy. If you simply need to support different types of DTOs, you could create an abstract class (or Interface) for your DTOs that the other DTOs inherit.

Comment: This is not the only method that needs to be implented, there are more. But this is the method I have the doubt.

Comment: You're going to have to give more concrete examples of the abstract class definition and inheriting classes. Your question as-is is "What if a developer doesn't want to follow the abstract method definition" to which the answer is simply "Then they should likely not be inheriting this abstract class in the first place."

Comment: aside: don't name a method setSomething if it doesn't change anything

Comment: as to your perceived problem: if developers need many variants of many  methods in its api, then the design is broken. Take a step back and think again on how to do it differently, what's really needed, what are the commonalities and the differences and then re-design along those lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, there are two ways to implement what you assumedly have in mind.
One is the use of an `interface` that `SortDto` and all other classes that can be used as a parameter must implement. This interface would then be the type of the (badly named) `setExitStatus` method. Within this interface, you need a method that generalizes the `sortDto.getTotalNumberOfPages() > 0` condition.

```
interface DtoExit {
    public boolean isDatos();
}
```

in SortDto

```
public class SortDto implements DtoExit {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean isDatos() {
        return sortDto.getTotalNumberOfPages() > 0;
    }
}
```

Your initial method becomes

```
protected String setExitStatus(DtoExit dto) {
    if (dto.isDatos()) {
        return "DATOS";
    } else {
        return "SINDATOS";
    }
}
```

The other possibility is to use polymorphism and create several `setExitStatus()` methods with different parameter types.

```
protected String setExitStatus(SortDto sortDto) {
    if (sortDto.getTotalNumberOfPages() > 0) {
        return "DATOS";
    } else {
        return "SINDATOS";
    }
}


protected String setExitStatus(AnotherDto anotherDto) {
    if (anotherDto.someCondition()) {
        return "DATOS";
    } else {
        return "SINDATOS";
    }
}

...
```

(Theoretically, there is a third approach, as you could have just one method with a very general parameter type, like `Object`, and do a lot of `instanceof` checks in the method body to find out the actual type of the parameter and handle it accordingly. I will not provide an example fo this approach as it is a dirty hack and definitely not recommendable)